# How to best design function that takes an unary predicate

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers, std-function, unary-function

I'm implementing a simple timeout-class which calls a given function when time runs out.

However I'm scratching my head on how to make the function constructor take an unary predicate, e.g. function pointer, std::function, functor or lambda, in the best case avoiding the performance hits if possible. What's important is that I want to allow capturing lambdas. Basically I want the same thing as is possible for the stl-functions std::find_if, std::for_each etc. with the caveat that I need to handle the calls asynchronously. How would I go about this?

Those are the barebones:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Ts>
class Timeout
{
public:
    using Function = /* ??? */;
    Timeout(uint32_t timeout_ms, Function fn) : timeout_{timeout}, fn_{fn} {
        /* portspecific invocation of task */
        internal_timer(this);
    }
    ~Timeout() {
        /* portspecific destruction of task */
    }

    static void internal_timer(Timeout* callobj) {
        /* portspecific delay */
        callobj->fn_(/* ??? */);
    }
private:
    uint32_t timeout_;
    Function fn_;
};

int main() {}
```

[CODE](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:6,endLineNumber:20,positionColumn:6,positionLineNumber:20,selectionStartColumn:6,selectionStartLineNumber:20,startColumn:6,startLineNumber:20),source:%27%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename...+Ts%3E%0Aclass+Timeout%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++using+Function+%3D+/*+%3F%3F%3F+*/%3B%0A++++Timeout(uint32_t+timeout_ms,+Function+fn)+:+timeout_%7Btimeout%7D,+fn_%7Bfn%7D+%7B%0A++++++++/*+portspecific+invocation+of+task+*/%0A++++++++internal_timer(this)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++%7ETimeout()+%7B%0A++++++++/*+portspecific+destruction+of+task+*/%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++static+void+internal_timer(Timeout*+callobj)+%7B%0A++++++++/*+portspecific+delay+*/%0A++++++++callobj-%3Efn_(/*+%3F%3F%3F+*/)%3B%0A++++%7D%0Aprivate:%0A++++uint32_t+timeout_%3B%0A++++Function+fn_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g490,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%270%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B14%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+4.9.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+4.9.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+4.9.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

*Side note*:
(1) It can be assumed that captured references at the callsite stay intact for the lifetime of the Timeout object.
(2) I have left out the portspecific parts, those are not the problem.

Comment: Can you use existing OS timer functions, such as Windows' WaitForSingleObject?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: No I'm on a embedded. But don't worry about that, I got that part.

Comment: What's the predicate supposed to take as parameter? Furthermore what's `Ts` for? Just make `Function` a template parameter and perhaps change `fn`  and `fn_` to references...

Comment: @fabian: It's supposed to take one parameter which would be the timeout object itself. Ts... is a remains from before (took it out). I'll try your suggestion.